# How can I do this in mongodb? Is that possible?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

suppose my collection has 3 documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b759065bfd90aa9cc925349"),
    "path" : "aa/bb",
    "data" : {
    "a" : "b"
    }
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7590cabfd90aa9cc9253aa"),
    "path" : "cc/dd",
    "data" : {
        "c" : "d",
        "path_list":[{"path_ref" : "aa/bb"}]
    }
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7590cabfd90aa9cc9253aa"),
    "path" : "ee/ff",
    "data" : {
        "e" : "f",
        "path_list":[{"path_ref" : "aa/cc"}]
    }
}
```

If data.path_ref exist, I need replace the string to the object (if the string is a valid path).  If not, do nothing.  So I want to get:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b759065bfd90aa9cc925349"),
    "path" : "aa/bb",
    "data" : {
      "a" : "b"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7590cabfd90aa9cc9253aa"),
    "path" : "cc/dd",
    "data" : {
        "c" : "d",
        "path_list" : [ {"path_ref" :  {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5b759065bfd90aa9cc925349"),
          "path" : "aa/bb",
          "data" : {
            "a" : "b"
          }
        }  }]
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7590cabfd90aa9cc9253aa"),
    "path" : "ee/ff",
    "data" : {
        "e" : "f",
        "path_list":[{"path_ref" : "aa/cc"}]
    }
}
```

I am new to mongodb. I do know something about aggregate. please let me know if it's possible or not?

=======
stackoverflow compliant I post to much code and do NOT have enough description. But I think I have describe my problme clearly. These just placeholder. Please ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation in 3.6.

```
db.col.aggregate([
{"$unwind":{"path":"$data.path_list","preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":true}},
{"$lookup":{
  "from":"col",
  "localField":"data.path_list.path_ref",
  "foreignField":"path",
  "as":"path_ref_lookup"
}},
{"$unwind":{"path":"$path_ref_lookup","preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":true}},
{"$group":{
  "_id":"$_id",
  "path":{"$first":"$path"},
  "data":{"$first":"$data"},
  "path_refs":{
    "$push":{
      "$cond":[
        {"$gt":["$path_ref_lookup",0]},
        {"path_ref":"$path_ref_lookup"},
        "$data.path_list"
      ]
    }
  }
}},
{"$addFields":{
  "data.path_list":{
    "$cond":[{"$eq":["$path_refs",[]]},"$$REMOVE","$path_refs"]
  }
}},
{"$project":{"path_refs":0}}
])
```

Comment: This is just an example. My real data is NOT this. BUT you give me the idea how to handle this problem.  Thank you very much!